# Need Dropdown to fill out db info on my page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can't seem to find my error. I have a dropdown in my form that I would like to have an onSelect event to cause it to call an AJAX script that queries the db and fills the info on a company address to fill in the form. The only way my drop down fills the fields is when I click on the save button for the form.

Here is my html:

```
<select id="est_for" name="estimate_for" onselect="show_info(this.value)">
<?php
if($estimate_for == NULL){
    ?> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Company</option> 
    <?php
}
else{
    echo '<option value="'.$estimate_for.'">'.$company_name.'</option>'; 
}
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM company');
$sql -> execute();
$result = $sql ->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $company_name = $row['company'];
        $company_id = $row['id'];
        echo '<option value="'.$company_id.'">'.$company_name.'</option>';
    }
}
else{
    echo'Cannot find company information<br>';
}
?>
</select>

<div id="company_info">
<?php                   
if($estimate_for != NULL){
echo $company_info['company'].'<br>'.$company_info['adr_street'].'<br>'.$company_info['city'].', '.$company_info['prov'].' '.$company_info['postal'].'<br>'.$company_info['country'];
}?>                         
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showInfo(str){
    if(str==""){
        document.getElementById("company_info").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            //IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            //IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("company_info").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    document.write(document.getElementById("company_info").innerHTML);
    xmlhttp.open("GET","create_estimate.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: `show_info` or `showInfo` ? I see a reference to a function not provided in your code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the code example you provided is missing some key information, and the rest of the form (about why it would work on a button press, and not a select onchange event)... but I believe your problem may be that you are doing this:

```
onselect="show_info(this.value)"
```

When your javascript function is defined like this:

```
function showInfo(str){ ... }
```

Note the name difference.

If you have more javascript than what you provided, which actually has the definition for a function called "show_info()" then please provide that. If not, that may be where you issue is occurring.

+1 on using prepared statements, but its kind of funny since there are no variables passed in the statement ;)

Comment: Thanks Randall! Geez...I changed all my function names and must have forgot to relect the changes on that one. I appreciate your help. It now appears to at least be going into the function. But I am now getting hung up on the following line: 
document.getElementById("company_info").innerHTML = this.responseText;

onChange is giving me a blank page and the line above is getting highlighted in the developer tool in Chrome. Any thoughts on this one? Or should I put it in a seperate question? Thanks!

Comment: Might be worthy on a new question, since it deals with ajax return values and handling of them. However you may wish to do a little debug spew on the response to see if you are first getting what you expect. You can do that using the dev console in your web browser (look under network), or adding `console.log( varNameStuff );` to your code.

Comment: You could look into jQuery though, which handles ajax and all of this very very smoothly with much less writing and lines of code. Its a beautiful framework (a crutch almost!). I have to admit, after many years of jQuery ... reading longhand javascript like you have above, gives my mind a fuzzy feeling haha.